# Error(3,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER Maxscore
BEFORE INSERT ON grade
REFERENCING NEW AS new
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  mins INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT min_score 
  INTO   mins
  FROM   courses
  WHERE  id = new.course_id
  ;
  IF new.grade < mins   
  THEN
    new.grade := 100 - mins;
  END IF;
END;
```

I do not no why I get this error:

```
Error(3,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I run the following query, but it does not return any rows:

```
select * 
from user_errors 
where name = 'maxscore' and type = 'TRIGGER';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name in `where name=` must be uppercase, Oracle by default has all object names in uppercase unless explicitly quoted (which is a bad idea to do in general).
Better is something like:

```
select err.name
,      err.type
,      err.line
,      err.position
,      err.text
from   user_errors err
join   user_objects ojt
on     ojt.object_name = err.name
and    ojt.object_type = err.type
where  attribute != 'WARNING'
and    message_number not in (905,304,364)
and    lower(err.text) not like '%ignored%'
and    lower(err.text) not like '%terminated%'
and    lower(err.text) not like '%triggering view is invalid%'
and    lower(err.text) not like '%has errors%'
order
by     ojt.last_ddl_time desc
,      err.name
,      err.line
/
```

The line numbers with triggers start AFTER the trigger definition, so at declare.

Actual problem

Add colon before EACH reference to new in trigger definition as in:

```
drop table grade

create table grade(a number, grade number, course_id number)

CREATE or replace TRIGGER Maxscore
BEFORE INSERT ON grade
REFERENCING NEW AS new
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  mins INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT min_score
  INTO   mins
  FROM   courses
  where  id = :new.course_id
  ;
  IF :new.grade < mins   
  THEN
    :new.grade := 100 - mins;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: thank you so much,it worked ,and trigger compiled without errors

Comment: but when i insert values into grade ,this error happens :SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.FAILED' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Comment: Sounds like a trigger in the system schema. Check 'select * from dba_triggers where owner='SYSTEM'. Is it valid? If not, make it valid. As editor you can use TOAD or Invantive Query Tool. Or drop it after saving the script using `drop trigger system.failed'. Create script using F4 in TOAD or query tool.